# Determine Whether the Display is On

Tags: xorg, 17.10, display-manager

What's the best way to determine whether the display is on in Ubuntu 17.10?  I'm writing a program in Go and I want it to do more work when the display is asleep (i.e. power-saving mode) and less work when the display is on (i.e. user doing other things that will demand processing power).  Is there some kind of user-space command I can use to query X.org or the display manager?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76479/querying-display-power-status-on-linux-xorg-on-command-line `xset q | grep Monitor`

Comment: @user688056 This won't work under Wayland (the default display system in 17.10) though.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Xorg with 17.10 and it works.  It would also be nice to know how to do it with Wayland though.